# Deleting rows not returning to original numbers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Just working with a database and some tests were done recently which checked the integrity of the setup.

As a result, a lot of test entries were added which were then deleted. However, when new entries are added, the ID number value continues from after the entries added.

**What I want**: 
ID increases by one from where it left off before the additional rows were added:
4203, 4204, 4205, 4206 etc.

**What is happening**:
 ID increases by one from after the additional rows ID:
4203, 4204, 6207, 6208 6209 etc.

Not sure where to fix this...whether in phpmyadmin or in the PHP code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't fix this, it __isn't__ a fault; and you shouldn't need to change it. Your PK should be an internal reference and if you use it to reference data in other table you'd need to update all those as well, leading to all kinds of risks and added performance overheads

Comment: Can I ask why you think you need to "fix" this correct and important behaviour of the database? If your code requires your ID's to be sequential, maby we could take a crack at helping you fix the code, instead of breaking the database.

Comment: I understand completely why this might need fixing, I test my code all the time by manually adding bogus database entries on a dev server to see how it will affect my code. I then need to reverse all changes. I document what I added so I can delete them as well and if there are any Foreign Key Constraints, then I fix those as well. This is a valid question. See answer below. It is sometimes important to make changes and then reverse those changes without it ever appearing that you made changes, hence the not missing AI PK

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into this before and I solve it easily with phpMyAdmin. Select the database, select the table, open the operations tab, and in the Table Options set the AUTO_INCREMENT to 1 then click GO. This will force mysql to look for the last auto incremented value and then set it to the value directly after that. I do this on a manually basis that way I know that when a row is skipped that it was not from testing but a deletion because when I test and delete the rows I fix the AI value.

Comment: When I tried this, it simply sets the value back to before after hitting Go.

Comment: @tect Sorry, I told you wrong and have edited my answer. Change the value to `1` not `0` and it will reset to your next AI. just tested and verified.

Comment: This seems like bad advice - definitely not a '2', maybe a '-2'

Comment: @Strawberry please explain why this is bad advice. It answers the question that was asked. and after the last edit it works 100%. Please see comment I made on question for a purpose that this may be needed. I would like to know why you think it is bad advice and offer to improve it as needed.

Comment: This is an inappropriate use of the AUTO_INCREMENT 'feature'. If the id has any meaning beyond the scope of database then it should not be incremented in this way.

Comment: @Strawberry I think you missed the whole question here. The OP said that he was testing and added rows and then deleted the rows after the test and just needed to fix the IDs so it did not display the missing Auto Incremented Values. This is not something I would recommend doing to a live production system on a regular basis, but only when testing as the OP stated. Quote: `Just working with a database and some tests were done recently which checked the integrity of the setup.` `As a result, a lot of test entries were added which were then deleted.`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this with an auto-incrementing ID key.
You could probably do it by assigning the ID to (select max(id) + 1 from the_table)

Comment: you would re-seed your auto increment to this but it won't always work in a multi-user environment where SELECT MAX is not going to be unique.  Best follow the advice of others and not even bother.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the primary key then recreate it, but this would reassign all the existing primary keys so could cause issues with relationships (although if you don't have any gaps in your primary key you may get away with it).

I would however say that you should accept (and your app should reflect) the possibility of missing IDs. For example in a web app if someone links to a missing ID you would want a 404 returned not a different record.

Comment: Accodring to the OP, the ID's were added by testing not production. So no one should ever be linking to an ID that would be missing. However I fully agree for a live production server to leave deleted IDs missing.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to "reset" the id values; I concur with the other comments concerning this issue.

The behavior you observe with AUTO_INCREMENT is by design; it is described in the MySQL documentation.

With all that said, I will describe an approach you can use to change the id values of those rows "downwards", and make them all contiguous:

As a "stepping stone" first step, we will create a query that gets a list of the `id` values that we need changed, along with a proposed new `id` value we are going to change it to. This query makes use of a MySQL user variable.

Assuming that 4203 is the `id` value you want to leave as is, and you want the next higher `id` value to be reset to 4204, the next higher `id` to be reset to 4205, etc.

```
SELECT s.id
     , @i := @i + 1 AS new_id
  FROM mytable s
  JOIN (SELECT @i := 4203) i
 WHERE s.id > 4203
 ORDER BY s.id
```

(Note: the constant value `4203` appears twice in the query above.)

Once we're satisfied that this query is working, and returning the old and new id values, we can use this query as an inline view (MySQL calls it a derived table), in a multi-table UPDATE statement.  We just wrap that query in a set of parentheses, and give assign it an alias, so we can reference it like a regular table.  (In an inline view, MySQL actually materializes the resultset returned by the query into a MyISAM table, which probably explains why MySQL refers to it as a "derived table".)

Here's an example UPDATE statement that references the derived table:

```
UPDATE ( SELECT s.id
              , @i := @i + 1 AS new_id
           FROM mytable s
           JOIN (SELECT @i := 4203) i
          WHERE s.id > 4203
          ORDER BY s.id 
       ) n
  JOIN mytable t
    ON t.id = n.id
   SET t.id = n.new_id
 ORDER BY t.id
```

Note that the old id value from the inline view is matched to the id value in the existing table (the `ON` clause), and the "new_id" value generated by the inline view is assigned to the id column (the `SET` clause.)

Once the id values are assigned, we can reset the AUTO_INCREMENT value on the table:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

NOTE:  this is just an example, and is provided with the caveat that this should not be necessary to reassign id values. Ideally, primary key values should be IMMUTABLE i.e. they should not change once they have been assigned.